# Invoking Javascript method in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript file(test.js) has Method1() method defined.

```
<script src="../Scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My html is defined as below. I get Method1() not found. Any ideas?

```
<p><input type="button" name="login" id="login" value="Login" onclick="Method1()"/> </p>
```

Here is the code in test.js declared...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function LoginToServer() {

......
}

</script>
```

Comment: So... how about showing us `test.js`?

Comment: U are talking about method or function.. if it's method then you should call it by creating instance of the class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `.js` file is a JavaScript code, not HTML markup.

This:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

is HTML markup, not a JavaScript code. You should remove that from `test.js`.

As you didn't show us exactly how your `Method1` is defined, I'll assume it is ok and this is the only error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `Method1()` isn't detected is because your `test.js` has a syntax error - the `<script></script>` tags.

Remove the opening and closing `<script>` tags from your `test.js` and everything should work properly.

```
function LoginToServer() {
//function code
}
```

`.js` files should only contain JavaScript code.

`.html` files may also contain JavaScript, but then the code has to be surrounded by `<script></script>`.

Also, you don't have to provide the `type="text/javascript"` because **HTML5** knows it is going to be JavaScript in-between those tags.